# How to make a Wacom tablet stylus slower (less sensitive)

Tags: input, cursor, tablet

The pointer moves too fast ([demonstration video](http://youtu.be/PIn6CEdE5kA)) when I use the tablet in relative mode after I run

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo stylus" Mode Relative
```

However, `xsetwacom  --list parameters` does not show an obvious setting to change this.

My mouse is set to accelerate rather a lot: `xset m 4 1`. Running `xset m 0 0` makes it possible to slow down the cursor in general but I need to do this only for the tablet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to scale the `Area` parameter. To get the current value:

```
$ xsetwacom get "Wacom Bamboo stylus" Area
0 0 14760 9225
```

The value might depend on my setup (two screens, 3840x1200 resolution) or on my tablet (Bamboo MTE-450) so it might be different in your case.

Multiply the values by the factor by which you want to slow down the pointer, for example to make the pointer 3 times as slow, run

```
$ xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo stylus" Area 0 0 44280 27675
```

To set the value when Xorg starts, you can write the command into `~/.xinitrc`

Note: it seems that until recently, BottomX and BottomY would have to be changed for this effect.

This solution was found thanks to an [Arch Linux forums thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=101648), which used BottomX but made it clear how to calculate and what the xsetwacom commands should look like.